# Laravel Mix Webpack - Bootstrap 4.1 links API to hidden jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel Mix in my project, and I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.1. Using the following code to load the libraries:

<sub>**bootstrap.js** *(originally generated by Laravel project for loading libraries)*</sub>

```
//...
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
//...
```

So I just tried triggering a modal and found this: `VM3990:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`. I then checked `window.$.fn` and I cannot find any Bootstrap defined functions.

Curious, I then proceed to use breakpoints to debug the packed JS file. And in the section when Bootstrap is imported/required, that instance of `$$$1`(local reference to jQuery) contained all the methods. Please see the following image:

[image]

I suspected Bootstrap loaded itself a separate instance of jQuery, and I found that to be true. And that instance of jQuery is loaded with `isGlobal == false`, so it wasn't exposed to `window` as `$`/`jQuery`. As I removed the line I load my jQuery, Bootstrap is still loaded and dropdowns can still be used if they are not triggered by my code.

[image]

The arrow in the image points to a jQuery portion in the file.

I don't know webpack that well, but has anyone faced this problem before? I'm just starting to learn how to use that and modules, so I might be doing something I shouldn't do.

Comment: Does your script contains defer attribute ? `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: @LukášIrsák I forgot to mention, but the file that loads the libraries is from the generated `bootstrap.js` by laravel. I used that file by `require("./bootstrap.js")` in another js file in which contain the logic of the page. And nowhere else did I alter the reference to `window.$`/`window.jQuery` after this.

Comment: So you are using npm run watch command to generate files correct ?
this command will load config from webpack.mix.js in that file you will find config like this:

`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`

So when you run npm it will compile your js/css to public folder.

Comment: @LukášIrsák I'm in fact using `npm run watch`. What about it?

Comment: Try to go to your  `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` or where is your main layout file located, and try to remove  defer attribute from script tag. I have similar problem with newest 5.6 laravel. It might be related

Comment: @LukášIrsák It's not loaded with the defer attribute.

Comment: Try to load a page in browser and in inspector console type `$(document);` what it says ?

Comment: @LukášIrsák JQuery runs fine, but without all of Bootstrap's API.

Comment: Try this in your boostrap.js 

`try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}` and then run npm run watch again. It's default config for laravel 5.6. This works ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171756/discussion-between-lukas-irsak-and-daniel-cheung).

Comment: @LukášIrsák That worked, but I didn't change the jQuery require from the dafault. Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `/resources/assets/js/boostrap.js`:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

this will require jquery module from `node_modules` folder.